# Git clone error "HTTP code 504 from proxy after CONNECT"

Tags: git, proxy, firewall, bitbucket-server

I'm working in a office behind a corporate firewall.  My System is windows7, using componentes consola. Usually I need to set up proxy connections to get GIT working with github.

But when I try to clone a repository sored in a private Stash (Atlassian) I get this error:

```
Cloning into 'apptest'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://xxx@xxx.xx.xx.xx:xxxx/apptest/apptest.git
/': Received HTTP code 504 from proxy after CONNECT
```

I have unsetted git proxy but I'm still facing same problem.
Please note that I'm using GITshell over Windows 7

Any help would be appreciated.

Regards

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include what OS (including version) and what shell (bash, cygwin, Windows cmd.exe, PowerShell, etc.) you are running this on.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Problem solved.

**Windows**: Before connecting **Bitbucket** (AKA **stash**) you need to clean all proxies from both Git and console environment:

```
SET HTTP_PROXY=
SET HTTPS_PROXY=
git config --global --unset http.proxy
git config --global --unset https.proxy
git clone http://yourUser@stashAddress:stashPort/apptest.git
```

But if you need to connect to public repositories like **github**, then it's necessary to define proxies again:

```
SET HTTP_PROXY=proxyaddress:port
SET HTTPS_PROXY=proxyaddress:port
git config --global http.proxy http://proxyaddress:port
git config --global https.proxy http://proxyaddress:port
```

I think it may be useful for other developers working behind corporate firewalls.

**Linux**

```
unset HTTP_PROXY
unset HTTPS_PROXY
git config --global --unset http.proxy
git config --global --unset https.proxy
git clone http://yourUser@stashAddress:stashPort/apptest.git
```

To define proxies again:

```
export HTTP_PROXY=proxyaddress:port
export HTTPS_PROXY=proxyaddress:port
git config --global http.proxy http://proxyaddress:port
git config --global https.proxy http://proxyaddress:port
```

*Take care with uppercase of environment variables. Some OS versions may need lowercase or may have defined lowercase variables by default.*

Comment: I got the same issue after tried several tricks to fix `UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT_LOCALLY` from here(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45884752/npm-err-code-unable-to-get-issuer-cert-locally).  Then this issue comes after I tried all of the suggestions in that post. Now it's fixed after I ran `git config --global --unset http.proxy`

Comment: That is great  @franva

Comment: This post has saved me multiple times. Has it not been set as the accepted answer?

Comment: To be honest @bpilling I have never considered that possiblity... Do I have to do anything to help flagging it as accepted answer?

Comment: I think you can just tick the check symbol next to? Not totally sure - I'm not super experienced on stackoverflow.

Comment: Wow, you are right... I forgot I was the asker :D, thank you

Answer (score 1):

***Problem Solved in SourceTree***

Hoping this might be of any help to other developers who use (like I do) ***SourceTree*** on Windows. Many thanks to @manuelbcd for his initial answer.

I was experience a similar problem (HTTP status code was 502 with the same error message) when I was trying to *fetch*, *pull* or *push* from the BitBucket, and no extra configuration was done in my local git configuration, and I could not understand why I was getting this error.

**SOLUTION**
In the list of the **Environment Variable** (Windows 7) HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY were set. Since I did not need them I removed from there and **relaunched** *SourceTree*.

In order to find the *Environment Variable* (Windows 7) click on *Start* and type `enviro`. At the top of the menu comes out the line `Edit environment variable...`, click on it, remove/rename the variable and **save**.

Relaunch SourceTree at the end.

Answer (score 0):

If you definitely need the proxy and can't remove it (eg: if you're on a corporate proxy) then just use the ssh to clone the repo.