# npm ERR! code UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT_LOCALLY

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, create-react-app

I am trying all possible ways to create a React application. I have tried Maven, and now I am trying `create-react-app` from Facebook Incubators.

When I tried to run the command `create-react-app my-app` in npm environment, it worked on my personal system with no issues. But, when I tried the same command in my work environment, I encountered the following error on my command line:

```
npm ERR! node v6.10.2
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT_LOCALLY

npm ERR! unable to get local issuer certificate
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
```

Comment: I also couldn't use `sudo` when I ran `npm install aws-sdk`. Running `sudo npm install aws-sdk` caused this error for me.

Comment: In case anybody attempted some variation of `npm config set cafile` before using another solution, that may be causing your UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT_LOCALLY issue. You can surgically undo that setting or if you are likely me and want a clean start, just rename your `.npmrc`

Comment: only `npm config set strict-ssl` false worked for me

Comment: In my case only `npm config set strictSSL false` worked... I use lerna - maybe that's the reason

Answer (score 467, accepted):

A quick solution from the internet search was `npm config set strict-ssl false`, luckily it worked. But as a part of my work environment, I am restricted to set the strict-ssl flag to false.

Later I found a safe and working solution,

```
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
```

this worked perfectly and I got a success message `Happy Hacking!` by not setting the strict-ssl flag to false.

Comment: I too, just reverted to using the HTTP version of the NPM repository (as opposed to https://registry.npmjs.org/), since my work proxy was causing issues (as it acts as a MITM, causing certification verification issues)

One day I will figure out the certificate issue, but I just needed to download a package, dang it!

Comment: For me I did this but I also couldn't use `sudo` when I ran `npm install aws-sdk`. Running `sudo npm install aws-sdk` caused this error for me.

Comment: I was getting the same error shown on this post so I ran `npm config set strict-ssl false` and `npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/ ` but I was still getting the error when running `sudo npm install aws-sdk` but when I dropped the `sudo` part and just ran `npm install aws-sdk` it worked.

Comment: for me nothing other than the setting of `npm config set strict-ssl false` does not work. I feel this is something the `node.js` and `npm` team should look into and document with a proper work around if it is not fixable for them.

Comment: I found this happened on Ubuntu if you install the `npm` package using `--no-install-recommends` as it does not get the `ca-certificates` package.

Comment: As you mentioned you were facing the same issue with the maven also, how did you solve it?
As we are setting this only for npm it resolved for it, but want to know how its solved for maven?

Comment: @PujanShah : I would say with maven you got to change the settings.xml file with the one being used widely across your enterprise, these issues will occur if you're connected to your enterprise network which blocks network connectivity. With the change in settings.xml one would be doing a kind of adding proxy to accomplish task of getting dependencies.

Comment: @srinivasy: The proxy is already set there in the settings.xml file, and for npm also proxy details configured in .npmrc file. The thing is earlier it was working but suddenly getting this certificate issue. As per me it is because of the enterprise network only but not able to figure out what might causing this issue.

Comment: @SivaniPatro with this command you are configuring your npm to use default and `request to http://registry.npmjs.org/pkgname will 301 (redirect) over to https://registry.npmjs.org/pkgname` 


[src]: https://blog.npmjs.org/post/142077474335/npm-registry-is-now-fully-https

Comment: @PujanShah can you be specific with the issue faced with maven. I have encountered with `PKIX path build failed error` with maven and I resolved it by importing my network certificates to keystore.

Comment: @Dinesh: I am also facing the same PKIX path build failed error. Let me share errors with npm and maven.
npm
npm ERR! code UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT_LOCALLY
npm ERR! errno UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT_LOCALLY
npm ERR! request to https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fcore failed, reason: u
nable to get local issuer certificate

Comment: maven
org.springframework.ws.client.WebServiceIOException: I/O error: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target; nested exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Comment: As while executing in browser it is allowing with valid certificate. But from local only it is restricting somehow.

Comment: @PujanShah This can happen if Java does not recognize the ROOT CA Authority for a remote server it tries to access.
Export the security certificate from the chrome browser and save as "certName.der"
Import cert into cacerts file using `keytool -import -alias example -keystore JAVACERTPATH/cacerts -file pathofCertName.der` 
*If `jssecacerts` also exists at same path as cacerts, import all certs from jssecacerts into cacerts using `keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore JAVACERTPATH/jssecacerts -destkeystore JAVACERTPATH/cacerts`

**JAVACERTPATH:C:/Program Files/Java/jrexxxxxx/lib/security

Comment: @Dinesh: My concern is to find common solution for both(npm,maven) as some days before it was working for both in corporate environment. As suddenly it stopped working for both I am not able to find the exact cause.

Comment: One more thing is if I try to hit the url https://registry.npmjs.org in the browser, it is giving the response by using proxy. So logically it also should allow from cmd also as proxy we are configuring in .npmrc file.

Comment: Downvoted as this is an insecure unencrypted channel and your workplace would not appreciate pulling libraries over HTTP only.  A better approach is Jordan's answer which allows you to define the trust store containing your company's certificates which means you can pull the libraries safely over an encrypted channel.

Comment: Disabling security isn't a solution. Alternatively it is a bad solution. See answer by Jordan for a good solution.

Comment: Is there an official StackExchange flag for "technically answers the question but is a terrible idea"?  We really need that here.  You want supply-chain attacks?  Because this is how you get supply-chain attacks.

Answer (score 91):

what may be happening is your company decrypts certain traffic and re-encrypts it with their certificate (which you probably already have in your keychain or trusted root certificates)

if you're using node 7 or later I've found this fix to be compatible with node and node-gyp (for Windows you'll need to do this differently, but you basically just need to add this environment variable):

`export NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS="absolute_path_to_your_certificates.pem"` (in Windows you may need to remove the quotes)

the pem file can have multiple certificates: https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#node_extra_ca_certsfile

make sure your certificates are in proper pem format (you need real line breaks not literal `\n`)

I couldn't seem to get it to work with relative paths (`.` or `~`)

This fix basically tells npm and node-gyp to use the check against the regular CAs, but also allow this certificate when it comes across it

Ideally you would be able to use your system's trusted certificates, but unfortunately this is not the case.

Comment: Where can i find .pem file in Windows. I searched the entire HardDisk for pem file found few levels deep inside Windows\System32. But it's not working

Comment: perfect.. we have a zscaler proxy. I downloaded public der certificate, converted to base64 encoded crt and in dockerfile added RUN export NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS="<path to cert">

Comment: To expand on this for mac/os x homebrew users it will be something like `export NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS=/System/Volumes/Data/opt/homebrew/etc/ca-certificates/cert.pem` (found with `find /System/Volumes/Data/opt/homebrew -name "*.pem"`).

Comment: This is the best practice, nearly all other answers are potentially very dangerous as those inferior answers allow MITM attacks.

Comment: Thanks! I too have Zscaler. I found the certificate locally on my machine and exported it by following [this guide](https://community.tenable.com/s/article/How-to-export-certificate-in-PEM-format-for-import-from-Windows).

Answer (score 47):

After trying out every solution I could find:

- Turning off strict ssl: `npm config set strict-ssl=false`
- Changing the registry to http instead of https: `npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/`
- Changing my cafile setting: `npm config set cafile /path/to/your/cert.pem`
- Stop rejecting unknown CAs: `set NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0`

The solution that seems to be working the best for me now is to use the [NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS](https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_node_extra_ca_certs_file) environment variable which extends the existing CAs rather than replacing them with the cafile option in your .npmrc file. You can set it by entering this in your terminal: `NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS=path/to/your/cert.pem`

Of course, setting this variable every time can be annoying, so I added it to my bash profile so that it will be set every time I open terminal. If you don’t already have a `~/.bash_profile` file, create one. Then at the end of that file add `export NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS=path/to/your/cert.pem`. Then, remove the cafile setting in your .npmrc.

Comment: Fourth option was a charm; `process.env['NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED'] = 0;`

Comment: In case of zscaler also, the fourth option (`set NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0`) is really the one that helped me. I had this issue in context of Electron. There is one more issue that electron build URL which is a git repo that seems to be blocked or not working. That needs to be fixed.

Comment: I have tried all answers provided above, none of them worked for me except `set NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0`

Comment: With Zscaler on, `set NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0` can help me.

Comment: @Buaban @Franva - I am on Zscaler too. Where exactly did you set this property ? In docker file ? something like this `RUN set NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0` .

Comment: @UdayKiran I don't use Docker so I'm not sure about your case. For my case, I run `set NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0` and then `npm install` on cmd on my laptop . I guess you have to add the command `RUN set NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0` above the command `RUN npm install` in your Dockerfile.

Comment: what are the dangers?

Answer (score 44):

Changing the NPM repo URL to HTTP works as a quick-fix, but I wanted to use HTTPS.

In my case, the proxy at my employer (ZScaler) was causing issues (as it acts as a MITM, causing certification verification issues)

I forgot I [found a script](https://gist.github.com/patik/84c0cbbcb65d5b9633c3) that helps with this and Git (for cloning GitHub repos via HTTPS had the same issue) and [forked it for my use](https://gist.github.com/rdundon/ceb2481aea727d50d674b7d485c72e7a)

Basically, it does the following for git:

```
git config --global http.proxy http://gateway.zscaler.net:80/
git config --system http.proxy http://gateway.zscaler.net:80/
```

and for Node, it adds `proxy=http://gateway.zscaler.net:80/` to the end of `c:\Users\$USERNAME\npm\.npmrc`

That solved the issue for me.

Comment: You might want to check which ZS cloud your company is configured in. Basically, check `ip.zscaler.com` for the cloud name and set that in the URL. Eg: if it says `zscalertwo.net` then replace with the following URL: `gateway.zscalertwo.net`

Comment: There are some things concerning about this script still like that it sets sslVerify in git to false globally and strict-ssl=false in npm, which is a security risk (malware getting added to your code).

Instead, you could ask your IT department (or whoever administers zscaler) to make a configuration change that will allow you to download your package as well as any devs going forward without having to do this script change locally. 

What you need is an SSL inspection bypass policy in zscaler for the domain the library comes from (ex. .download.sentry-cdn.com)

Comment: @DanWuensch Yeah, I haven't used this in some time (no longer work where ZScaler is used on my machine), but that was one concern on the script I forked at the time. I just pointed to the Zscaler proxy and did something (don't recall) to install the internal Zscalar certificates. 

It's still funny how this is my top answer on SO year later. My contribution to the community I suppose 

Comment: Zscaler sucks 

Answer (score 16):

Had the same error.  Looks like it is related to SSL certificates.  If you are using NPM for public packages (don't need the security of HTTPS) you can turn off strict SSL key validation with the following command.

This might be the simplest fix if you're just looking to install a few publicly available packages one time.

```
npm config set strict-ssl=false
```

Comment: There is inherent risk of doing this, if you are a victim of a nefarious man-in-the-middle attack the package could be modified as you download it.

Comment: @AlexKeySmith You are right.  However, the odds are pretty low.  This might be the only option for some.  Caveat Emptor

Answer (score 13):

What is your OS?  On Ubuntu I was able to fix this error by running

```
npm config set cafile /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
```

to tell npm to use my system's certificate store.  Debian uses the same system certificate path, I'm less familiar with other distributions and OSes.

(I don't like the other answers that all turn off certificate verification and allow man-in-the-middle attacks.)

Comment: Do you know what certificate store it uses by default? I was surprised that this fix worked, but it did the charm for me.

Answer (score 8):

Zscalar **update policy** help me to make network calls, after trying couple of work around mentioned.

**Workarounds tried Before Zscalar update:**

- npm config set strict-ssl false
- npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
- set NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0

**Update policy**(Highlighted in yellow) in Zscalar app helped me to fix "unable to get local issuer certificate" issue.

[image: Open Zscalar App -> click]

Comment: Same issue here. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 6):

In my case, at some point I set my global config to use a cert that was meant for a project.

`npm config list`

```
/path/to/global/.npmrc
NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS = "./certs/chain.pem"
```

I opened the file, removed the line and `npm install` worked again.

Answer (score 6):

For me the issue was VPN, I disconnected the VPN and "npm i" command worked with no fail.

Comment: Yep, VPN agent running locally was the reason. Try stopping the service and do the "npm i".

Answer (score 6):

`npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/`

If this code trick didn't work for you then **try to run your application from home directory.**. It worked for me.

Comment: I tried all other options but nothing worked as I am behind a Enterprise Network Firewall. However above helped me in installing a new react project.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error when I tried to update npm, but had a really old version (1.3.6 !) installed from yum in AWS Linux.  I was able to manually install a newer npm version and everything was remedied.

Answer (score 0):

Setting `NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS` in the terminal did not work for me for some reason, same like how `export http_proxy=proxyurl` in the terminal didn't work and instead I needed to do a `npm config set proxy yourproxyurl:port` and `npm config set http-proxy yourproxyurl:port` (you can verify existing proxy, if any, via `npm get proxy`).

I had to supply `--cafile` parameter for it to explicitly work, something like this:

> sudo npm install -g cordova --cafile /System/Volumes/Data/opt/homebrew/etc/ca-certificates/cert.pem

Answer (score 0):

This is not necessarily a fix, but the way I resolved this was by switching node versions with `nvm use <version>`.

I looked at the logs for the failed `npm i` and noticed it was using node 19... didn't even know it went up that high!

Answer (score 0):

I have been getting the same error when using the `OpenAI` client for NodeJs. Turned out my computer was protected using Zscaler which caused the issue. The following fixed the problem for me:

```
import https from 'https';

const openai = new OpenAI({
  httpAgent: new https.Agent({
    rejectUnauthorized: false,
  }),
});
```

Please be aware that `rejectUnauthorized` should not be set to `false` for remote environments like prod stacks.

Answer (score -1):

**Its very easy to fix this issue.**

**ERROR**

```
npm ERR! code UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT_LOCALLY 
npm ERR! errno UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT_LOCALLY
npm ERR! request to https://registry.npmjs.org/yarn failed, reason: unable to get local issuer certificate  
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
```

**Solution**

If you are in organization or intranet then use below commend.

> npm config set registry
> https://type_your_org_repo_fqdn

other wise

npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/

Comment: I upgraded my node and using `nvm` on linux I changed my node version to the latest and everything worked fine

Answer (score -1):

Some schematics use yarn under the hood and throw the same error.

`yarn config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org`

Answer (score -1):

This is what worked for me (on a Mac 10.15.7).

My issue was I tried this command...

```
npm install eslint --save-dev
```

...and got this error message...

```
npm ERR! code UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT_LOCALLY
npm ERR! errno UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT_LOCALLY
npm ERR! request to https://registry.npmjs.org/eslint failed, reason: unable to get local issuer certificate
```

...I googled one of the error messages and ended up on the stack overflow issue you are reading now.

I then tried one of the suggestions above, i.e.

```
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
```

...then, I again tried...

```
npm install eslint --save-dev
```

...and got the same error message.

**Then I did something unique.  I connected to my company's vpn.** (This is the *opposite* of what someone (i.e. @mask) suggested.  They said they turned OFF their vpn!)

I tried...

```
npm install eslint --save-dev
```

...for the third time and it worked like a charm.  Problem solved. (-:

(Aside: I wonder if my first attempt to fix this, i.e.

```
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
```

...was necessary?)

Comment: Using http is not the solution, it's a workaround but also a bad practice. Not sure why you get the error though. Maybe you have some company proxy?

Answer (score -1):

I deleted the .npmrc file from C:\Users\MyUser and it worked

Answer (score -4):

doing the following steps solved it for me.

```
npm config set strict-ssl=false
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
npm config set cafile /path/to/your/cert.pem
set NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0
```

Comment: Wrong answer. It is unsafe to set strict-ssl to false, and unset to set NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED to 0.