# UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT_LOCALLY error for users behind company firewalls

Tags: javascript, npm, pubnub

I am using company laptop. And firewall can not be set off. My machine is windows-10. When I try to implement pubnub code I am getting following error:

UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT_LOCALLY

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Most likely you need to whitelist IP addresses and/or domain names. Otherwise, all communication is of ports 80/443.

Comment: Is this same issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45884752/npm-err-code-unable-to-get-issuer-cert-locally/45884819#45884819

Answer (score 2):

This could be caused by using a proxy as well.

Try using the command `npm config set strict-ssl false` or `npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/`