# Jupyter Extension Installs Fail as Not Valid NPM Package

Tags: python, npm, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I am trying to install the Jupyter Plotly extensions per their [directions](https://plot.ly/python/getting-started/), see section heading: JupyterLab Support (Python 3.5+). However, installation of any package listed fails with a *ValueError...not a valid npm package*. In full disclosure, this is my first stackoverflow post. If information is missing, please let me know. I'm an engineer that uses Python, not someone deeply versed in the underlying toolsets.

**System**

- Windows 10
- Python 3.7.5
- node 12.13.0
- npm 6.9.0

I don't know if this is pertinent but I am trying to do this installation from withing a python environment. What I did before attempting extension installation (*beware: no idea what best practice is*).

- Created folder for python environments folder (>*c:\projects\python\environments*)
- In new folder, created jupyterLab environment (>*python -m venv jupyterLab*)
- Started shell (>*jupyterLab\Scripts\activate.bat*)
- Installed Jupyter Lab (>*pip install jupyter lab)
- Verified Jupyter Lab opens and works

Next I tried to install the ploty extensions as graphs were not rendering.

**Command line entry**

*jupyter labextension install @jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager@1.0 --no-build*

**Result**

*ValueError: "@jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager@1.0" is not a valid npm package*

I get this error no matter which package or version I try to install from Plotly's directions.

**Things tried**

- Python 3.8.0
- Uninstalled and reinstalled nodejs and npm
- Rolled back Juptyer Labs to v 1.0.0
- Rolled back NPM to various versions from 6.7 through 6.13
- Checked that nodejs in path (*suggested in a forum*)
- Check that C:\Users{myUserId}\AppData\Roaming\npm was in path (*suggested in a forum*)
- Good-ole standby...restarted computer

**Log output**

```
Node v12.13.0

C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.CMD" pack @jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager@1.0npm notice
npm notice package: @jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager@1.0.3
npm notice === Tarball Contents === 
npm notice 2.3kB  package.json        
npm notice 1.5kB  LICENSE             
npm notice 1.9kB  README.md           
npm notice 277B   lib/index.d.ts      
npm notice 380B   lib/index.js        
npm notice 5.4kB  lib/manager.d.ts    
npm notice 14.0kB lib/manager.js      
npm notice 1.9kB  lib/output.d.ts     
npm notice 5.2kB  lib/output.js       
npm notice 830B   lib/plugin.d.ts     
npm notice 6.7kB  lib/plugin.js       
npm notice 956B   lib/renderer.d.ts   
npm notice 3.3kB  lib/renderer.js     
npm notice 216B   lib/semvercache.d.ts
npm notice 862B   lib/semvercache.js  
npm notice 375B   schema/plugin.json  
npm notice === Tarball Details === 
npm notice name:          @jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager         
npm notice version:       1.0.3                                       
npm notice filename:      jupyter-widgets-jupyterlab-manager-1.0.3.tgz
npm notice package size:  11.8 kB                                     
npm notice unpacked size: 46.2 kB                                     
npm notice shasum:        48f60ba3224327a7af21aef0edf9400202c3f34f    
npm notice integrity:     sha512-/VNnECOfq731D[...]wRYjB2nuNGpeg==    
npm notice total files:   16                                          
npm notice 
jupyter-widgets-jupyterlab-manager-1.0.3.tgz

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "c:\projects\python\environments\jupyterlabs\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab\debuglog.py", line 47, in debug_logging
    yield

  File "c:\projects\python\environments\jupyterlabs\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab\labextensions.py", line 82, in start
    ans = self.run_task()

  File "c:\projects\python\environments\jupyterlabs\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab\labextensions.py", line 103, in run_task
    for arg in self.extra_args

  File "c:\projects\python\environments\jupyterlabs\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab\labextensions.py", line 103, in <listcomp>
    for arg in self.extra_args

  File "c:\projects\python\environments\jupyterlabs\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab\commands.py", line 316, in install_extension
    return handler.install_extension(extension)

  File "c:\projects\python\environments\jupyterlabs\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab\commands.py", line 517, in install_extension
    info = self._install_extension(extension, tempdir)

  File "c:\projects\python\environments\jupyterlabs\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab\commands.py", line 1373, in _install_extension
    info = self._extract_package(extension, tempdir)

  File "c:\projects\python\environments\jupyterlabs\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab\commands.py", line 1444, in _extract_package
    raise ValueError(msg % source)

ValueError: "@jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager@1.0" is not a valid npm package

Exiting application: jupyter
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Were you able to find something @Jeff Dawson

Comment: Were you able to find something +1

Answer (score 1):

It is an old question, but if anyone else encounter a similar problem, then:

I had a similar problem trying to install the jupyterlab/toc. In the end it seems my problem was caused by my company VPN solution (Zscaler) and logging out of it I was able to install the extension with no problems.

If you are not just able to log off, then you might find inspiration for a solution in https://stackoverflow.com/a/45884819/5816356. For me this made npm happy, but then I had a similar issue with yarn and instead of solving that I just logged off zscaler.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try `jupyter labextension install "@jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager"` first. If that does not work you  can run `jupyter labextension list` and delete the widget taz file in extensions.

I develop the extension in local, always get the error. My system is MacOS. But I think you can have a try.