# While I'm trying to create React app this particular error is coming

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, npm

```
C:\Users\souvik das>cd documents

C:\Users\souvik das\Documents>npx create-react-app blog

Creating a new React app in C:\Users\souvik das\Documents\blog.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

npm ERR! code ERR_SSL_CIPHER_OPERATION_FAILED
npm ERR! errno ERR_SSL_CIPHER_OPERATION_FAILED
npm ERR! Invalid response body while trying to fetch https://registry.npmjs.org/react-dom: F42A0000:error:1C800066:Provider routines:ossl_gcm_stream_update:cipher operation failed:c:\ws\deps\openssl\openssl\providers\implementations\ciphers\ciphercommon_gcm.c:312:
npm ERR!

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\souvik das\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-05-04T16_20_42_133Z-debug-0.log

Aborting installation.
  npm install --no-audit --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts cra-template has failed.

Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting blog/ from C:\Users\souvik das\Documents
Done.
```

Comment: What are the contents of `C:\Users\souvik das\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-05-04T16_20_42_133Z-debug-0.log` - Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45884752/npm-err-code-unable-to-get-issuer-cert-locally

Comment: someone else have same [issue](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/12000)

Comment: Do you mind sharing the npm/nodejs versions you're using? Seems like a version related issue.

Comment: node version is v18.1.0

Answer (score 1):

have you tried updating the package by using `npm update create-react-app`?

Comment: yes i did. but still the problem persist

Comment: node version is v18.1.0

Comment: try returning to node version **16.13.1** and npm version **8.1.2**. If an error still comes up the try ```npm cache clear --force``` and ```npm i -g @sap/cds-dk``` then run ```npx create-react-app appName``` Then things should go back to normal, lmk if not.

Comment: Hey, thanks, man! This is so silly, I tried everything from other stack threads, but, this worked for me! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue , just go to windows settings -> Network reset -> reset now
and hit the reset .. and restart your PC . it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Got the same `Provider routines:ossl_gcm_stream_update:cipher operation failed`  error on Node 18 with npm 8.x during `npm install`. Running the below command worked for me.

> npm cache verify