# New Jode.js project in visual studio: Missing NPM

Tags: node.js, npm, visual-studio-2022

I'm going through a basic tutorial on how to create a Node.Js project in Visual Studio. I create the project and there is an "npm" folder with some packages listed such as : body-parser, cookie-parser, etc. They all have "(missing)" next to them. I've gone through this new project setup a few times. Sometimes when I right click on the package the "Install npm Package" is greyed out. Sometimes it isn't. When it isn't and I select "Install npm package", it does absolutely nothing.

This is a new project. There is no Git repository or anything. This is literally just a new Node.js project straight out of the box. Does anyone know why these npm packages are missing or why I can't install them?

Comment: What tutorial are you following? Typically you'd just run `npm init -y` command to create package.json file and that is all you need to do to create a node js project

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/javascript/tutorial-nodejs?view=vs-2022

Answer (score 0):

I found this, which isn't related to Sisual Studio, but someone trying to install express via the command line:

[npm ERR! code UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT_LOCALLY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45884752/npm-err-code-unable-to-get-issuer-cert-locally)

I found some stuff in the logs about a local cert not found. I had to run `npm config set strict-ssl` and suddenly it worked.

An alternative answer that was suggested is the following, if you are looking for a better long-term solution:

```
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
```