# npm ERR! unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: reactjs

I want to install react on vs code i have already install node js but it showing me npm error i dont know how to solve this issue. Here is the Screenshot [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/knh1V.png) of error please help i tried somw ways by searching but couldnt resolve the issue .

I tried some commands like

```bash
npx create-react-app my-app
cd my-app
npm start
```

am expecting solution for the error which i am not able to solve.
here is the error

```js
npm ERR! code UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT_LOCALLY
npm ERR! errno UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT_LOCALLY
npm ERR! request to https://registry.npmjs.org/create-react-app failed, reason: unable to get local issuer certificate

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Dev\npm-repository\npm-cache\_logs\2022-12-15T19_15_44_004Z-debug-0.log
```

Answer (score 0):

I found two feasible solutions in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45884752/npm-err-code-unable-to-get-issuer-cert-locally)

I'd recommend you to try this two different solutions.

1. Run `npm config list`

   ```
   /path/to/global/.npmrc
   NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS = "./certs/chain.pem"
   ```

   Remove the last line and then `npm install`
2. Add `proxy=http://gateway.zscaler.net:80/` to the end of `c:\Users\$USERNAME\npm\.npmrc`

There's also other solutions that disable ssl protection but that is risky and isn't recommended.