# I try doing 'npx create-react-app' and it complains 'UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT_LOCALLY'

Tags: reactjs, npm, npx

I tried doing:

npx create-react-app my-app

It complains:

UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT_LOCALLY

I got the same result with:

npm init react-app my-app

Comment: Does this answer your question? [npm ERR! code UNABLE\_TO\_GET\_ISSUER\_CERT\_LOCALLY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45884752/npm-err-code-unable-to-get-issuer-cert-locally)

Answer (score 0):

The quick solution is **npm config set strict-ssl false**,
Try this command it will work!

```
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
```

Thanks :).