# How do I fix npm ERR! code ERR_SSL_CIPHER_OPERATION_FAILED when creating Electron or React app

Tags: node.js, openssl, git-bash

I tried many solutions I found in the web, from reinstalling node js, installing the new openssl version, reinstalling git bash (console), allowed gitbash and nodejs through firewall, and even formatted the whole PC. Nothing worked,

Error below:

```
npm WARN exec The following package was not found and will be installed: create-electron-app@6.0.5
npm ERR! code ERR_SSL_CIPHER_OPERATION_FAILED
npm ERR! 7C020000:error:1C800066:Provider routines:ossl_gcm_stream_update:cipher operation failed:c:\ws\deps\openssl\openssl\providers\implementations\ciphers\ciphercommon_gcm.c:320:
npm ERR!
```

after running it again I get this error:

```
module.exports = bind.call(Function.call, Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty);


TypeError: bind.call is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Keba\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\36f5f21e8c68ce75\node_modules\has\src\index.js:5:23)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1275:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1329:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1133:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:972:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1157:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:119:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Keba\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\36f5f21e8c68ce75\node_modules\@electron-forge\cli\node_modules\is-core-module\index.js:3:11)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1275:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1329:10)

Node.js v19.6.1
```

Comment: Can you confirm if this answer works for you? https://stackoverflow.com/a/45884819/2593672

Comment: none of them have worked

Answer (score 1):

For some reasons, some people can't connect to the registry via https.
This can be fixed by setting `npm config` in terminal

```
npm config set strict-ssl false
```

Comment: Did not work, still get the error even for other npm commands like: 
`npm ERR! code ERR_SSL_CIPHER_OPERATION_FAILED
npm ERR! BC0D0000:error:1C800066:Provider routines:ossl_gcm_stream_update:cipher operation failed:c:\ws\deps\openssl\openssl\providers\implementations\ciphers\ciphercommon_gcm.c:320:
npm ERR!
`

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a new folder on other local disks. make sure you have not created the application C drive. Do not name the app as react;react-dom;react-scripts