# How to solve 'UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT_LOCALLY' error when using https module with OpenWeatherMap API

Tags: node.js, web, react-fullstack

So, I tried to run my application using nodemon then I am getting one error
I was expecting it to work smoothly and don't throw me any error.
When I remove the 'https' node module from the .js file then it works fine but as soon as I insert the 'https' module and use the https.get() method then I am getting this error.

This is the thing which I got-

> [nodemon] starting `node app.js`
> Server started on port 3000
> node:events:489
> throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
> ^

> Error: unable to get local issuer certificate
> at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (node:_tls_wrap:1560:34)
> at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:511:28)
> at TLSSocket._finishInit (node:_tls_wrap:977:8)
> at ssl.onhandshakedone (node:_tls_wrap:771:12)
> Emitted 'error' event on ClientRequest instance at:
> at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:495:9)
> at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:511:28)
> at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
> at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
> at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
> code: 'UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT_LOCALLY'
> }

Node.js v20.2.0
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

```
const express = require("express");
const https = require("https");

const app = express();

app.get("/", function(req, res) {

    const url = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&APPID={API_ID}";

    https.get(url, function(response){
        console.log(response);
    });
    res.send("Server is up and running");
});

app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log("Server started on port 3000");
});
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45884819/2955337